# ¿Código en segundo plano en Django?

Tags: python, django, procesos-en-segundo-plano

estoy realizando una aplicación web con Django y necesito que una sección de código se ejecute en segundo plano. Se trata de un motor de Speech, concretamente pocketsphinx. Éste código es llamado a través de una vista. El funcionamiento de la vista es ejecutar el código Python del speech, el cual activa el micro, comienza a escuchar una frase y la decodifica como un string, retornando a la plantilla dicho string. Mi intención es que despúes de esto, no termine la función, sino que continúe reconociendo speech. Una redirección a la misma vista no serviría ya que tendría que volver a arrancar el motor de speech (y esto tarda un tiempo que no es admisible).

```
def startSpeech(request):
    decoder = setupDecoder()
    stream = setupAudicoConf()
    phrase_recognized = decodePhrase(decoder, stream, 'grammar')
    phrase_filtered = filterFich(phrase_recognized)
    print "Phrase recognized:", phrase_recognized
    print "Phrase filtered:", phrase_filtered
    return render_to_response('speech.html', locals())
```

Existe algo en Django para correr funciones en segundo plano o necesitaría algo más?.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Pues existe Celery que puede ayudarte con eso, pero lo que veo así a nivel de consejo es que si eso tienes pensado subirlo a un servidor en la nube, no tendrás micrófono para escuchar algo, y pues haces ese proceso desde el servidor cuando lo ideal es hacerlo desde el navegador, lo que tendrías que hacer es saber como recibir y guardar esos datos

Comment: Leí algo sobre Celery, creo que es algo así cómo un encolador de tareas. Echaré un vistazo @GermanAlzate. Y la idea no es que vaya a la nube. Es un servidor multimedia implementado sobre una raspberry pi.

Comment: Releyendo tu pregunta, veo que el motor de Speech puede estar activo antes de hacer la petición. Que corra en un servicio a parte, no necesariamente con django. Ya que recuerda que Django está hecho para trabajar en un servidor web y no creo que existan muchos servidores web que permitan ejecutar varios hilos de tu app

Comment: Eso sería lo ideal. Mi idea es que nada más arrancar la raspberry arranque el motor de speech. Una vez esté funcionando, el servidor django podrá llamar al motor de speech y este empiece a escuchar y a reconocer comandos de voz, con los cuales ejecutará una acción en el servidor web dependiendo de la orden del comando de voz. Que servidor me recomendarías para correr el código de speech en background?

Comment: Hola soy nuevo en esto y siento no poder ayudarte con tu pregunta, pero sí creo que puedes ayudarme tu a mi.
Estoy intentando transcribir el speech que entro por el micrófono a un string para poder trabajar con él y programar respuestas en función de la entrada y no encuentro como hacerlo.
Uso también pocketsphinx con python sobre Ubuntu.
Podrías darme algún sitio donde lo explique o mostrarme como lo consigues?
Gracias de antemano.